# Read from standard output

Tags: c#, dll

I have a function in dll file and it write something to standard output and standard error. How can I read what this function wrote in to a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect the standard and error output of your application to stringwriters, and then consume them. Like this:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(), errorWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            var stdOut = Console.Out;
            var stdErr = Console.Error;
            Console.SetOut(writer);
            Console.SetError(errorWriter);
            try
            {
                MyDllWritesThings();
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.SetOut(stdOut);
                Console.SetError(stdErr);
            }
            Print("StdOut", writer);
            Print("StdErr", errorWriter);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void Print(string what, StringWriter writer)
    {
        writer.Flush();
        using (var reader = new StringReader(writer.ToString()))
        {
            var wowInteresting = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine($"{what}: '{wowInteresting}'");
        }
    }

    private static void MyDllWritesThings()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Secret output");
        Console.Error.WriteLine("Secret error output");
    }
```